# Move a payment profile from sandbox to production account

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Is it possible to move a payment profile from the authorize.net sandbox into a production CIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandbox and production environments are separate and it's not possible to move sensitive data from one system to the other.